# Java Console encoding issue

Tags: java

```
package com;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "echojhj sdfsdfsdfsdf");
    Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    final String CP866 = "Cp866";
    //not work
    //IOUtils.copy(errorStream, new PrintStream(System.out, true, CP866));
    //process.getInputStream().close();

    //work
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream, CP866));
    String s = null;
    while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

}

Actual console output:

```
windows-1251

"echojhj" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
```

Expected console output:

```
windows-1251

"echojhj" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

I try to use PrintStream for specifying System.out encoding, but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it's not working. Any idea ?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, then what is the error? Do you get unexpected output? What did you expect and how is this different from what's actually happening?

Comment: I get unexpected console output. I expect this: "echojhj" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use this method to copy data:

[IOUtils.copy(InputStream, Writer)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.Writer))

As the documentation states:

> Copy bytes from an InputStream to chars on a Writer using the **default character encoding** of the platform.

The encoding that you specify for PrintStream is the encoding for the output stream, not the encoding with which the errorStream will be parsed. So you should use this method instead:

[IOUtils.copy(InputStream, Writer, Charset)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.Writer,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: As I understand there is only one way: 1.Create writer and pass to copy(). 2.After copy finished manually call flush() or close() to see the result on the console?

Comment: @Kostya-OniL yes, if I understood your code correctly